# How to explain the behavior of git reset --soft && git checkout

Tags: git

I've been using `git` for one year and I'm able to use the common git commands, such as `git add`, `git commit`, `git reset`, `git checkout`, `git rebase` etc.

Today, I found something about `git checkout` that I can't explain.

As all we know, `git checkout <branchname>` can switch to the `<branchname>`. As my understanding, this command do the following things:

- switch branch pointer
- update the `HEAD` pointer
- update the working zone and the index

In a word, this command does the three steps so that it can switch the branch.

And as all we know, `git reset --soft` can reset the `HEAD` pointer.

Now let me show you something "weird" to me.

```
git checkout br1
git reset --soft br2
git checkout br2
```

As my understanding about `git checkout` above, I thought that `git reset --soft br2` was nonsense, which means that as my own opinion, the three commands are equivalent to `git checkout br1 && git checkout br2`.

However, after executing these three commands, I find that the last commit of `br1` is brought to the branch `br2`, which means that the last commit of `br1` has been copied to the current working zone and the current index.

Well, I'm confused now. I suddenly feel that the commands `git checkout` and `git reset` are kind of strange, I think I might have misunderstood the command `git checkout` for a long time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And as all we know, git reset --soft can reset the HEAD pointer.

True, but that's incidental. `git reset` lets you arbitrarily move the current branch to a new commit, and then checks that commit out. `--soft` vs `--hard` just say what to do about the working directory and index.

```
git checkout br1
git reset --soft br2
```

This moves br1 to the same commit as br2 while keeping your working directory and index the same as br1.